# Why HTML5 image srcset loads two images at the same time?

Tags: html, image, srcset

I've got a problem with uderstanding why html5 img attribute doesn't work corectly? 
In this chunk I set srcset, and when I have screen width 320px, i gonna get image-xs.jpg, but browser shows image-md.jpg and I think it because of loads to images. Is it a bug or I don't understand something? Explain please and won't tell about tag picture and img inside, I wonder, why specifically img works so?

```html
<img
        sizes="(min-width: 700px) 80vw, 100vw"
        srcset="img/image-xs.jpg 375w,
          img/image-sm.jpg 480w,
          img/image-md.jpg 768w"
        alt="City">
```

[image]

Comment: What is the pixel density? IIRC doesn't it calculate based on the browser width AND pixel density, so if its 320px wide but 3x, it will pick an image at least 640px wide if available

Comment: Set pixel density in browser to 1x, 2x and 3x but it doen't works. In point of fact browser track breakpoint coreclty and loads necessary image, but besides needed image it loads one more image and it is always image-md.jpg and this image (i think) override first image